# Return results in order based on minimum date in array from Cosmos DB

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I currently have data stored in cosmosdb fetchable like so

`SELECT t.code, t.departures from t`

which returns like

```
    {
        "code": "BAHVB2",
        "departures": [
            {
                "code": "14601",
                "startDate": "2022-09-13T00:00:00",
                "endDate": "2022-09-20T00:00:00",
                "available": true,
                "definite": false,
               
            },
            {
                "code": "14602",
                "startDate": "2022-09-27T00:00:00",
                "endDate": "2022-10-04T00:00:00",
                "available": true,
                "definite": false,
                
            },
            {
                "code": "14603",
                "startDate": "2022-12-10T00:00:00",
                "endDate": "2022-12-17T00:00:00",
                "available": true,
                "definite": false,
                
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "BBFLL2",
        "departures": [
            {
                "code": "14618",
                "startDate": "2022-08-30T00:00:00",
                "endDate": "2022-09-04T00:00:00",
                "available": true,
                "definite": false,
                
            },
            {
                "code": "14619",
                "startDate": "2022-09-09T00:00:00",
                "endDate": "2022-09-14T00:00:00",
                "available": true,
                "definite": false,
                
            },
            {
                "code": "14620",
                "startDate": "2022-09-19T00:00:00",
                "endDate": "2022-09-24T00:00:00",
                "available": true,
                "definite": false,
                
            },
            {
                "code": "14622",
                "startDate": "2022-10-11T00:00:00",
                "endDate": "2022-10-16T00:00:00",
                "available": true,
                "definite": false,
                
            },
            {
                "code": "14623",
                "startDate": "2022-11-07T00:00:00",
                "endDate": "2022-11-12T00:00:00",
                "available": true,
                "definite": false,  
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

How would I create a query to order the results based on the first/minimum startDate ?

as in code: BAHVB2 has the minimum 2022-09-13, and BBFLL2 has the minimum 2022-08-30, so BBFFL2 should appear first?

Is there a good way to perform where clauses on this as well? I am at a crossroads as every guide ive seen so far isnt so explanatory

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job

```sql
SELECT t.code, t.departures 
FROM t
ORDER BY MIN(ARRAY(SELECT d.startDate FROM d IN t.departures))
```

Comment: I get an error that an aggregate is not allowed in order by, is what im asking possible with cosmos?

Comment: it might not be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973333/how-to-order-results-of-a-query-by-the-results-of-an-aggregate-function-in-comos